# Using Python / Numpy `as_strided` to efficiently create overlapping patches from non-overlapping sequences

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `2-d` numpy array of shape `NxM` which represents `M` contiguous samples from `N` different sequences. I need to present patches of `L` samples (`L << M`) covering the entire dataset as a `2-d` numpy array. There is too much data to construct a new dataset by simply copying of all the patches.

If there was a single sequence, it would be very straight forward to generate the overlapping patches without copying any data using the `as_strided` trick:

```
patches = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(data, shape(N*M-L+1,L), strides=(8,8))
```

The problem with this approach for my data is that it produces patches that overlap separate sequences.

I can also see how to generate a 3-d array of shape `N,M-L+1,L` using something like:

```
patches = np.lib.stride_ticks.as_strided(data, shape(N,M-L+1,L), strides=(8*M,8,8))
```

This produces the correct patches, but I am not sure how to collapse the first two dimensions into one.

There are obviously several SO answers related to `as_strided`, but I could not find any that address these particular requirements.

Any ideas are appreciated.

**Edit**: Short example follows

Here is an example of using `as_strided` to make a `3-d` array that almost accomplishes the task:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> a 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(3, 3, 2), strides=(32,8,8))
>>> b 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [10, 11],
        [11, 12]]])
>>>
```

The issue with trying to flatten this `3-d` array into `2-d` as suggested by @Divakar is that the reshaping produces the correct data but does so by making a copy which creates an unmanageable amount of data for the actual problem at hand:

```
>>> c = b.reshape(-1,b.shape[-1])
>>> c
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10],
       [10, 11],
       [11, 12]])
>>> b[0][0][0] = 9999
>>> c
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10],
       [10, 11],
       [11, 12]])
>>>
```

Comment: Reshape : `patches.reshape(-1.patches.shape[-1])`?

Comment: But don' be surprised if reshaping produces a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj, yes, reshaping does produce a copy. While this is elegant code wise, unfortunately it doesn't address the issue.

Comment: Forget the copy issue for now.  In my testing I don't see how the reshape of the 2nd `patches` is any different from the 1st patches.  You may need to provide a small example so we can see clearly what you are trying to produce.